# Create new jQuery Array by Comparing a Single Value in Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

There are a lot of posts on this, but my JS chops are quite there yet to figure out a solution for my case.

I have two arrays, one is a hardcoded array (Array2 in screenshot) of Google Lat/Lng variables and the other is an array constructed by iterating over DOM elements(Array1 in screenshot).  I need to compare Array2 against the dynamically created Array1 from DOM and create a new Array3 of only the Array2 objects that are found in Array1.  This will be the array I iterate over to create Map Markers.  Below are my code samples.

**Array1**

```
var gdata = new Array();

$("table tbody tr:gt(0)").each(function (i) {
    gdata[i] = new Array();
    $(this).children('td').each(function (ii) {
        gdata[i][ii] = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

**Array2**

```
var markers = [
    ['a0', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a10', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a20', 32.840777, -117.244864],
    ...
]
```

[image]

Comment: The match should be with the texts in the first column of Array1, or with values in any column? Do you need Array1 for other purposes, or could we propose another structure?

Comment: Yes, I can move it to column 1.

Comment: No, no, that is not what I ask. So the matching value could be anywhere in the HTML table, not just in column 1?

Comment: @trincot I only care about the [0] position because this is the array of Lat/Lng for my markers.  Both target objects are in the [0] location now and a new screenshot has been uploaded.  Hopefully this makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your check seems to only deal with values in the first column of the HTML table, you don't need to read all of it in `gdata`, just the first column. Then, you could turn the text from that first column into an object with the texts as keys, which allows for faster look-up:

```js
var gdata = {};
$("table tbody tr:gt(0)>td:first-child").each(function () {
    gdata[$(this).text()] = true;
});

var markers = [
    ['a0', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a10', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a20', 32.840777, -117.244864],
    ['c3', 32.840777, -117.244864],
];

var array3 = markers.filter(function(row) {
    return row[0] in gdata; 
});

console.log(array3);
```

```css
td, th { font-size: 9px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1>
   <tr>
      <th>heading</th><th>heading</th><th>heading</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>b</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>a20</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>a0</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If you have ES6 support, you could use a `Set` and arrow functions instead:

```js
var gdata = new Set($("table tbody tr:gt(0)>td:first-child")
                    .map( (i,td) => $(td).text()).get());

var markers = [
    ['a0', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a10', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a20', 32.840777, -117.244864],
    ['c3', 32.840777, -117.244864],
];

var array3 = markers.filter( ([id]) => gdata.has(id) );

console.log(array3);
```

```css
td, th { font-size: 9px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1>
   <tr>
      <th>heading</th><th>heading</th><th>heading</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>b</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>a20</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>a0</td><td>123</td><td>123</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like:

```
var results = []; // the results array

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) // iterate for every marker key
{
   results = results.concat(gdata.filter(function(item) { return item[8] == markers[i][0]; }));
}
```

In js we can use the **filter** method in order to retrieve only a portion of a given array by a query statement.. in this case we used a comparison of every marker key against the entire gdata array.. at the end - we are concating the relevant items for each marker to the destination results array

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to `filter()` the static list if any (`some()`) of them match the dynamic list:

```js
var markers = [
    ['a0', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a10', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a20', 32.840777, -117.244864]
];

var dynamic = [
    ['a0', 32.840801, -117.244842],
    ['a0zz', 32.840801, -117.244842]
];

var found = markers.filter( m => dynamic.some( d => d[0] === m[0]) );


console.log(found)
```

Comment: Good question. I think you are right. The `some()` function would just check something like `d.indexOf(m[0]) < -1`

Comment: I am getting `an expression is expected` at `=>` in my IDE, even though I tried the code and it works in console.